# Issue of Overwrite jQuery object

Tags: jquery, json

I have following jQuery code but it does not give expected output.

```
$serize = [];
$obj = {};
$input_data = [22,33,44];
$obj.name = "Sadik";
$obj.data = $input_data;
$serize.push($obj); 

$input_data = [11,21,32];
$obj.name = "Palsaniya";
$obj.data = $input_data;
$serize.push($obj); 

alert(JSON.stringify($serize));
```

**Current Output**

```
[{"name":"Palsaniya","data":[11,21,32]},{"name":"Palsaniya","data":[11,21,32]}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{"name":"Sadik","data":[22,33,44]},{"name":"Palsaniya","data":[11,21,32]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jvmL90bx/)

You just have to reinitialize the `$obj`

```
$serize = [];
$obj = {};
$input_data = [22,33,44];
$obj.name = "Sadik";
$obj.data = $input_data;
$serize.push($obj); 

$obj = {};
$input_data = [11,21,32];
$obj.name = "Palsaniya";
$obj.data = $input_data;
$serize.push($obj); 

alert(JSON.stringify($serize));
```

Comment: Objects and arrays are pushed by reference. Built-in types like numbers are pushed as a copy. Hence, you must re-initialize the object